# Selenium.findElement(By.()) using cssSelector in Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbPb8.jpg

The above is the HTML content... I’m trying to get the text where it says "Your ZIP/Postal Code"

Right now I have:

```java
WebElement typeOfEntry = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".subscribe-modal.step-1.field-label"));
System.out.println(typeOfEntry.getText());
```

Comment: have you tried with xpath?

Answer (score 0):

You should try CSS selector. Something like:

```java
WebElement typeOfEntry = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#js-zip-modal-step label"));
System.out.println(typeOfEntry.getText());
```